# Words "List of Tables" and "Acronyms" Appear After Their Respective Lists

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I have used the following code to produce a list of figures, tables and acronyms at the start of my thesis (taken verbatim from a template provided by my university.

This produces the lists of figures, tables and acronymns exactly as I would expect. However, in the PDF produced, immediately after the list of tables, the phrase "List of Tables" appears at the top of a blank page on its own. Similarly, after the list of acronyms, the word "Acronyms" appears at the top of a blank page on its own. I thought these were simply placeholders before I had insterted any tables or acronymns, however, they continue to appear even after a correctly formatted list.

I appreciate any advice on how to correct this!

EDIT: Removing the hyperref package seems to correct the issue with the list of tables but not the acronyms.

EDIT: Working Example Added

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\title{Thesis Problem \\ PhD Thesis}
\author{A N Other}

\newacronym{ipcc}{IPCC}{Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Declaration
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
\begin{quote}
    \centering
    This thesis is the result of the author...... \\[5pt]
\end{quote}
\vspace*{\fill}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\printglossaries

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
The \acrfull{ipcc} is an international body comprising 195 member states.
\begin{table}[!t]
    \caption{Merits of Plan A vs B}
    \label{table:Merits}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X| }
        \hline\hline 
        Plan A & Plan B \\
        \hline
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Higher cost
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Lower cost
        \end{itemize}  \\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[!t]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=14.5cm]{image.png}
    \caption{Annotated image.}\label{fig:image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal document (with dummy contents, not necessary to include any of your real input), that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I have edited the original post with a working example. I still get the words "Table of Contents" appearing after the table of contents and "Acronyms" appearing after the table of acronyms. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The hyperref package does not cause any problem, but in your table you need to say \\ before the \hline. When I run your (corrected MWE it compiles correctly, but does not produce the list lf acronyms, which I have not tried.

Comment: Haven't tested anything, but you say that these headers appear at the top of blank pages.  Do the blank pages at the ends of (some) chapters (the ones that end on a right-hand page) also have headers, and if so, so you want those headers, or should blank pages be *really* blank?  If really blank, an adjustment to `\cleardoublepage` is in order.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would need to put an extra \\ in the table, C. Peters. The table part compiles correctly at my end and produces the expected result. Barbara Beeton, are you suggesting that two pages are being created for the lists of acronyms and tables but there aren't enough acronyms or tables to populate it, so it's giving me a titled page with no content to make sure each section starts on a left hand page? If so, how would I could live with that for now as a lot more tables and acronyms will be added.

Comment: Remove `\topskip0pt` or use at least `\topskip1sp` (minimal positive value).

Comment: Off topic: page numbers of lof, lot and list of acronyms in toc are wrong. Do not add the lists manually to toc. You can load package `tocbibind` with option `nottoc`: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. For the list of arconyms add options `toc=true` and `ucmark=true` : `\usepackage[acronym,toc=true,ucmark=true]{glossaries}`. Replace `\printglossaries` by `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,toctitle={List of Acronyms}]`. If the title in toc and document should be the same, use `title={List of Acronyms}` instead `toctitle={List of Acronyms}`.